# Cannot get Construct 2 Pong sample to work with AirConsole. Everything loads except paddles

Tags: construct-2, airconsole

I'm not having much luck with Construct 2 and AirConsole.
I've followed the information on here: https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/construct2 and downloaded the example file and installed AirConsole
Software Versions: Construct 2 r239 Airconsole 1.4.9.2
This is what I get when I run the simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVWx2.png

Cross posted on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/airconsole/comments/5v53x4/dev_question_cannot_get_construct_2_pong_sample/

EDIT: Updated image.

Comment: Hi! This is not the exemple controllers, not the exemple project either?

Comment: Used the wrong image in my post originally.... http://i.imgur.com/zo8ATRj.png

Comment: Can you please share a picture with the link you are using for the pong example, if you are running locally I recommend using Appserv so you can easily mount your HTML for testing, here is how my pong runs: [C2 Pong example with normal debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4NDa.png) How this can help you.
Regards